# Update a td cell based if the first cells checkbox is selected

Tags: jquery

I am pretty rubbish when it comes to jquery so im looking for a little help.

I have a table with a number of rows and 5 columns.
Column1 contains a checkbox and column 4 contains an empty TD. I have a textbox that I want to be able to add a comment into and for a button to be able to update any rows TD where the rows check box has been selected.

Getting the selected checkbox is easy enough but I dont really know how to update the TD.

Can anyone help out?

Thank you

```
<tr class="t-state-selected"><td>                
                <input name="checkedRecords" type="checkbox" value="e85b7931-1c62-11e1-8244-4040dde94e2e " title="checkedRecords">
            </td><td>Some info</td><td>ABC</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>123</td><td></td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

A an example of one of the tr in my table. I want to see if checkedRecords is seletected and if it is then add the value "Updated :)" into the last td.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, added a tr example. I do also make all answers however I have been stuck on 68% forever

Comment: Hmm, strange, then I'm taking back my last sentence. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an `id` to all the cells you want to update. E.g.

```
<td id="col_0_row_0"></td>
```

In your jquery, check for the relevant checkbox for each row and update the `td` if required

```
$("#col_0_row_0").children().remove();
$("#col_0_row_0").append("Some Text");
```

Comment: Hi oddtar. Thats what I would have done but its been generated by a control that doesnt allow me to add an id or class

Comment: Hey Dan, you can use the `:nth-child` keyword for achieving this. E.g. `<script>$("table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(1)").append("<span>blabla</span>");</script>`

Comment: I am not sure if this is effective but it seems to do what I need it to. 
 var s = ($(this).parent().nextAll(":nth-child(3)"));

Comment: Hahaha, indeed :) Seems to be more or less the same approach anyway!